# Value not inserting in DateTime column using Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to insert value in DateTime column with Entity Framework but it throwing error on db.SaveChanges() function. There are 2 DateTime columns but exception throwing for only one (entry.OT_Date) with no maximum detail.

```
             var entry = new OT_Request_N();
                entry.Emp_ID = StaticFunctions.WindowUserId;
                entry.slno = db.OT_Request_N.Max(x=>x.slno)+1;
                entry.OT_Date= otD;
                entry.OT_Time_Req = hourRequest;
                entry.Remarks_Req = sError.ReqRemarks;
                entry.Req_Sent_On = DateTime.Now;
                entry.Supervisor_ID = sError.ManagerID;
                entry.Approve_Status = 0;

                db.OT_Request_N.Add(entry);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Here is SQL table Design

[image]

Here is class generated in edmx file

```
    public partial class OT_Request_N
{
    public int slno { get; set; }
    public string Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Req_Sent_On { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OT_Time_Req { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor_ID { get; set; }
    public string Remarks_Req { get; set; }
    public string Remarks_App { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OT_Time_App { get; set; }
    public string Approved_By { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Approve_Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Approved_On { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Operations { get; set; }
    public string AltReq_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Is_alert_sent { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OT_Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check what value is coming in otD ?

Comment: please share exact error which you might be getting in exception.

Comment: You should include error details in your question however it is small.

Comment: make sure that you are passing correct date time format in otD object.

Comment: It is impossible to help without knowing what the error you are receiving is. Please include the error message, exception type, stack trace, and the declaration and any modifications thereafter of `otD`